# Python selenium and fuzzy matching

Tags: python, fuzzy-comparison

I'm using `Selenium` to populate some drop down menus. These dropdown menus are fairly dynamic.

What I have though are values that could be in the dropdown, for example:

```
<select>
    <option>Red, wooly, jumper, large, UK</option>
    <option>Blue, wooly, jumper, small, USA</option> 
    <option>Red, wooly, scarf, small, UK</option>
</select>
```

Ideally, what I'm looking to do is select the option that closest matches the following string

```
'Red, wooly, small, UK'
```

This would select the 3rd item from the dropdown

Could this be done with some kind of matcher? If so, how would I select the correct element from the dropdown?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you tried using a regular expression?? Python regex to match the third line, or even using pythons builtin .find() method.  Since you're using selenium you can find all the options elements, iterate over each element, check the text of each element, and compare it to your string.

For example

```
elem = browser.find_elements_by_tag_name("option") 
for ele in elem:
  if ele.get_attribute("innerHTML").find('Red') > -1 and ele.get_attribute("innerHTML").find('wolly') > -1 and ele.get_attribute("innerHTML").find('small') > -1 and ele.get_attribute("innerHTML").find('small') > -1:
    #TODO
```

However that gets kind of long so I would use a regex, for example:

```
import re
elem = browser.find_elements_by_tag_name("option") 
for ele in elem:
  m = re.search(r'(Red,.+wooly,.+small,.+UK)', ele.get_attribute("innerHTML"))
  if m:
    print m.group(1)
```

if `.get_attribute("innerHTML")` doesn't get the inner text try .text()

Comment: would `m` give me the element/text?

Comment: m is the match, if you want to print the text element, see the update above that i'm going to make now, that should not only make the correct element,  assuming that selenium found all the tags, but if you print group(1) it should print Red, wooly, scarf, small, UK

Comment: I just used `if m: element.click()`

Comment: well yeah, if m  then thats the element you want to click (in my example it would be ele.click()), printing m.group(1) will just print the stuff between the <option></option>, I misread your earlier comment, either way, using regex is a good way to match fuzzy, i use this site to check my regex before putting it into code http://pythex.org/

Answer (score 0):

You can get the text from options and then compare the your text, like below:

```
elms = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("select > option")
ops = []
for el in elms:
    ops.append(el.text)

s = 'Red, wooly, small, UK'.split(", ")

weight = []

for op in ops:
    n_occurance = 0
    for text in s:
        if text in op:
            n_occurance += 1

    weight.append(n_occurance)

most_like = weight.index(max(weight)

elems[most_like].click()
```